# Real reason tournament director of Teplice Open in Czechia tried to ban Ukrainian players?

Tags: fide, tournament, tournament-directors

I have just seen that [FIDE has stepped in](https://twitter.com/julienpretotRTR/status/1664258758518755331) and told the organisers of the Teplice Open that they may not ban Ukrainian players from the tournament. Searching for more information as to why a tournament in another country would ban Ukrainian players I came across [this article](https://www.channelnewsasia.com/sport/chess-czech-tournament-does-u-turn-ukraine-players-after-warning-3531441) which says:

> Last Sunday, the Teplice Open organiser told the NSS chess website that "the current political situation does not favour chess and the tournament is deprived of grandmasters from Ukraine, which even though they have signed up, we cannot accept for serious reasons, although reluctantly."
>
> Nudged on Facebook by Czech International Master Tadeas Kriebel about those "serious reasons", organiser Pavel Kirs replied: "My personal opinion is that Ukrainian men of military age should fight with a weapon in hand on the battlefield for their country and not in peace with wooden piece in hand on a chessboard for money."

This smells very fishy. Then I found [this tweet](https://twitter.com/KramarenkoMari3/status/1663975176227225600):

> The #Czech Teplice Open tournament blocked the applications of Ukrainian chess players aged 18-60.
> According to the organizer, "men should fight for the country, and not play chess for money."
> **However, russians were admitted to the tournament - Anton Demchenko and Gleb Dudin**.

Does anybody know the background story here? What is really going on?

Comment: The full interview (in çz) is [here](https://www.nss.cz/rrozhovor-s-pavlem-kirsem,-aneb-16.-rocnik-teplice-open-je-za-dvermi), it really seems like a political message by the organizer (for/against which side I don't know), nothing really more and Fide has stepped in ([reuters](https://www.reuters.com/sports/chess-czech-tournament-does-u-turn-ukraine-players-after-warning-2023-06-01/))